# Rails Creation through association & Collection vs. Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, collections

I am confused about the some Association concepts in Active Records.

I have three models User, Bank and Bankaccount. Both the User and the Bank models "has_many" Bankaccounts and the Bankaccount model "belongs_to" both the User and the Bank models. I use the following syntax to create a Bankaccount through its association with User

```
@bankaccount = @user.bankaccounts.create(bankaccount_params)
```

What is the appropriate syntax if I want to create a bankaccount object through both the association with User and the association with Bank?

My second question is related to this one. Right now, because I am not sure how to create a bankaccount through both associations, I handle the association with the Bank by putting the parameter manually

```
  bank_id = params[:bank_id]
```

However, this seems to trigger some issues down the road when I want to iterate through all the bankaccounts and retrieve the name of the associated bank.

In my view I have

```
<% @bankaccounts.each do |bankaccount| %>
<%= bankaccount.bank %>
```

I obtained a list of these

```
#<Bank:0x007f7a66618ef0>
#<Bank:0x007f7a664c9ab8>
```

If I tried to get the name of the bank

```
<% @bankaccounts.each do |bankaccount| %>
<%= bankaccount.bank.name %>
```

I get an undefined method name for nil class. I do get the name of the bank in the console with these simple lines

```
bankaccount = Bankaccount.find(1)
bankaccount.bank.name
```

Could you anyone give me more background on those concepts and provide me with the appropriate syntax to loop accross my collection @user.bankaccount and for each bankaccount retrieve the name of the associated bank?

Thanks.

Comment: On what fields are you binding the tables ? I am assuming you have bank_id , and user_id as forign keys in  "Bankaccount."

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to choose one association to create a bankaccount through, then set the second separately:

```
@bankaccount = @user.bankaccounts.new(bankaccount_params)
@bankaccount.bank = somebank
@bankaccount.save
```

Or

```
@bankaccount = @bank.bankaccounts.new(bankaccount_params)
@bankaccount.user = someuser
@bankaccount.save
```

In addition, I don't see why setting the second association manually with a param would inherently cause the other problems you are experiencing. This should be fine (assuming a bank with this id actually exists):

```
@bankaccount.bank_id = params[:bank_id]
```

If you choose to assign a foreign key as a parameter, you can roll it into strong parameters and pass it into the bankaccount model with everything else. For example:

```
def bankaccount_params
  params.require(:bankaccount).permit(:bank_id, ...)
end
```

You last issue regarding arrays vs. collections depends on what you are trying to do. First, if you are particularly interested in the bankaccount's bank name, make it easier to get:

```
class Bankaccount
  belongs_to :bank
  ...
  def bank_name
    bank.name
  end
end
```

For those who buy into such things, this also prevents a Law of Demeter violation.

If you are simply trying to list the names of banks for @bankaccounts in a view, try leveraging Rails partials with something like this:

app/views/bankaccounts/index.html.erb

```
<%= render @bankaccounts %>
```

app/views/bankaccounts/_bankaccount.html.erb

```
<%= bankaccount.bank_name %>
```

More on this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

If you're looping over @bankaccounts for another reason, the code you provided should work, given that @bankaccounts represents ActiveRecord relations and not a  simple array:

```
<% @bankaccounts.each do |bankaccount| %>
  <%= bankaccount.bank_name %>
<% end %>
```

Since you're getting an undefined method error, your problem probably stems from how you are building @bankaccounts. If you are doing exactly this...

```
@bankaccounts = @user.bankaccounts
```

...and you've verified that everything is properly associated in the console, then your problem is likely unrelated to arrays or collections.